# Combine Two ulong Hashes into New ulong Hash

Tags: hash, cryptography

I have two strings that are hashed into a ulong (using Google's CityHash) during separate processing stages and now must combine the two hashes into a new hash without significantly increasing the risk of a hash collision.

I know that XOR has some issues (such as Value ^ 0 = Value), but given that the two input values should already be well distributed, I suspect that I can combine the hashes like

```
ulong hash = hash1 ^ hash2; // hash1 and hash2 are ulong hashes of strings
```

Is there something wrong in this approach, or is there a better approach that does not add significant computational overhead?

Comment: Why is this tagged *cryptography*? My spidey-sense is tingling!

Comment: @NikBougalis: Because the hash should meet cryptographic standards of distribution.  No worries, I'm not confusing encryption and hashing :-)

Comment: @NikBougalis: Yeah I have a little "how are hashing and encrypting different" snippet on hand because that topic comes up so often.

Comment: You don't really want cryptographic hashes, and that's good because CityHash doesn't give it to you. XORing two CityHashes should be perfectly fine.

Comment: @GregS: Agreed, CityHash does not have cryptographic hash properties.  However, my own testing and testing of others indicates it's pretty darn good (while also quite fast).  I just don't want to go from "pretty darn good" to "eh" when combining the two hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @GregS's comments and my own further reading, I believe I'm not seriously degrading the hash distribution by using a simple XOR.

That is the approach that seems wisest.

Comment: Well, it depends. If you want the result for "ab" to be the same as for "ba", it's Ok. If you want them to be different than you'll at least have to shift/multiply one of the partners.

Comment: @wildplasser: Given the otherwise strongish hash distribution, I think that is a non-issue.  That's much more likely to be an issue when the to operands have a usual range much smaller than the size of the hash (e.g. when hashing the X,Y coordinate on the screen/a graph).

Answer (score 1):

The boost library does this in a fairly simple way.

You would probably need to calculate the golden number at 64 bits.

The computation would be:

```
ulong hash = hash1 ^ ( hash2 + 0x9e3779b9 + (hash1 << 6) + (hash1 >> 2);
```

The number 0x9e3779b9 is 2^32/phi I believe. Phi is the golden ratio. The division by an irrational number tries to add "randomness" in a deterministic fashion.

Comment: This isn't bad, but again this short of thing should not be used *anywhere* where a cryptographically secure hash is desired.

Comment: Why the left and right shifting of hash1?  Is that amount of shift appropriate for a 64-bit number?  Do you have a reference for the "boost" way?